# Google charts API doesn't decode HTML entities although I passed them decoded

Tags: php, javascript, php-5.3, google-visualization

So I'm using the google charts API , However when I decode HTML entities passed to the API with the data , the charts are displayed and the titles still contain the un-decoded HTML entities and I see stuff like ‡ instead of the symbol that it represents ..

Below is an example .. How could I make sure the data is decoded in the chart
http://i1283.photobucket.com/albums/a542/semi852/Capture_zps33daa7b6.png

```
<?php
session_start();
// disable any caching by the browser
header('Expires: Mon, 14 Oct 2002 05:00:00 GMT');              // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT'); // always modified
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');  // HTTP 1.1
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');                                    // HTTP 1.0
require_once('../config.php');
require_once '../_includes/auxiliary_functions.php';


?>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>Charts</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" title="Style CSS" href="report_assets/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" title="Style CSS" href="report_assets/cwcalendar.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" title="Style CSS" href="report_assets/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <script src="../_js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
            <script src="../_js/timer.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

            <?php
            $data =  $_GET['data']; 
            $title = $_GET['title'];
            $data = strip_tags(DecodeSpecialChars(html_entity_decode($data))); 

?>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&#135;/g, '‡;');
}
</script>


          <script type="text/javascript">

              google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

            //set callback
            google.setOnLoadCallback (createChart);

            //callback function
            function createChart() {

                //create data table object
                var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();


               //create data table object
                var dataTableMulticolumn = new google.visualization.DataTable();


                //define columns for first example
                dataTable.addColumn('string','Question');
                dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Answers');

                //define rows of data for first example
                dataTable.addRows([<?php echo strip_tags(DecodeSpecialChars(html_entity_decode($data))); ?>]);





                //instantiate our chart objects
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart (document.getElementById('Chart'));

                //define options for visualization
                 var options = {width: 1550, height: 900,legendFontSize:14,fontSize:25,is3D: true, title: "<?php echo $title; ?>"};

                //draw our chart charts
                chart.draw(dataTable, options);

               //register callbacks
                google.visualization.events.addListener(eventsChart, 'onmouseover', showDetails);
                google.visualization.events.addListener(eventsChart, 'onmouseout', hideDetails);

            }

            function showDetails(e) {
                switch (e['row']) {
                    case 0: document.getElementById('details0').style.visibility='visible';
                        break;
                    case 1: document.getElementById('details1').style.visibility='visible';
                        break;
                    case 2: document.getElementById('details2').style.visibility='visible';
                        break;
                    case 3: document.getElementById('details3').style.visibility='visible';
                        break;
                }
            }


            function hideDetails(e) {
                switch (e['row']) {
                    case 0: document.getElementById('details0').style.visibility='hidden';
                        break;
                    case 1: document.getElementById('details1').style.visibility='hidden';
                        break;
                    case 2: document.getElementById('details2').style.visibility='hidden';
                        break;
                    case 3: document.getElementById('details3').style.visibility='hidden';
                        break;
                }
            }

   </script>

        <?php           

        echo "<div class='charts'>"; 
        echo "<div id='Chart'></div>";
        echo "</div>";
        ?>
```

Comment: How does `DecodeSpecialChars` look like ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are still searching for an answer to this, the solution is to use the javascript Unicode character value (eg `\u2021` for ‡), not the HTML code.